# Can't use lazy static integer constant for the size of an array

Tags: rust

The following code gets the page size from `sysconf` to optimally read files from the filesystem. I am unable to create the buffer with the size:

```
lazy_static! {
    static ref PAGE_SIZE: i64 = sysconf(SysconfVariable::ScPagesize).unwrap();
}

fn main() {
    let mut buffer = [0; *PAGE_SIZE as usize];
}
```

Gives me:

```
error[E0080]: constant evaluation error
  --> src/main.rs:6:30
   |
6  |         let mut buffer = [0; *PAGE_SIZE as usize];
   |                              ^^^^^^^^^^ unimplemented constant expression: deref operation
```

I thought it is a operator priority problem and tried to wrap with it braces but the result still the same:

```
error[E0080]: constant evaluation error
  --> src/main.rs:6:30
   |
6  |         let mut buffer = [0; (*(PAGE_SIZE)) as usize];
   |                              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ unimplemented constant expression: deref operation
```

How to use the constant above for allocating a buffer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not compile-time constant at all. Use `vec!` for anything that can't be determined compile-time:

```
let mut buffer = vec![0; *PAGE_SIZE as usize];
```

Currently there's no compiler level support for Variable-Length Arrays (VLA).

Comment: Okay, this is not a compile-time constant. The docs also say so. Is there any other way to read page size once and to use it everywhere? Is there any way to write page size into a real compile-time constant? `static PAGE_SIZE: i64 = ...` maybe? Anything?

Comment: You can achieve that via a compiler plugin, or build script combined with `env!`. I cannot recommend allocating on stack, because allocating a page on stack may cause overflow.

Comment: @TatsuyukiIshi: I would like to note that using a build script and `env!` should be done carefully in the event of *cross-compiling*. The target and host systems may have different page sizes. Thus, I would instead suggest using `cfg`.